# Python string formatting - TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and currtly playing a little bit with it.

So I'm trying to use string formatting and get an error message for following code:

```
domain = 'myway.net'
inet = 'the internet'

line2 = "Play the way through %s using %s" (inet, domain)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What doing I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're missing the format operator in between the string and the arguments? Try adding `%` in between:

```
line2 = "Play the way through %s using %s" % (inet, domain)
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Did not see that.. :-X